# No Option for Azure Board Tab in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-boards

we have added the Azure Boards app to one of our teams within Microsoft Teams and we can create new work items, search work items etc all fine.

We now want to bring our Azure DevOps kanban board into the team as a tab and looking at various articles this should be possible. But when we click the '+' on the channel tabs we have no options that relate to Azure Boards.

Has this feature been scrapped in recent versions? Are the available tab options restricted by the users permission level?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Azure boards app in teams have a bot & messaging extension. There is no way to add Azure boards app as channel tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To bring your Kanban board into Microsoft Teams, click the + icon to add new tab. Find the Azure DevOps icon and select **Azure DevOps**.

[image]

Then select the Organization. Once you have authenticated and selected your organization, you will be displayed a screen to select a **Kanban board** or Dashboard.

[image]

**Prerequisites**:

1.You should have Office365 account in order to integrate Azure DevOps Services with Microsoft Teams.

2.Only Azure DevOps organizations in the same organization (AAD tenant) can be used to integrate with your Microsoft Teams account.

For details .please refer to this [document](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/#azure-devops-kanban-board--dashboards-in-teams). In addition, you can also [create a service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=azure-devops#kanban-board--dashboards-in-teams-azure-devops-services-only) with Microsoft Teams to bring Kanban board into Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0):

You add the Azure Boards app for Microsoft Teams from the App Store

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/integrations/boards-teams?view=azure-devops#add-the-azure-boards-app-to-microsoft-teams

Direct Link:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/product/office/WA200000644?tab=Overview